# Passing a Class into a function

Tags: iphone, ios

I've got a function which creates a few different NSOperation subclasses.

They all use the same parameters the only thing that is different is the Class name.

At the moment I've got a function with a repeating block of code running through the function.  Is it possible to pass the Class into a function so that the function can create the objects for me?

i.e.

```
- (void)createOperationSubclass:(Class*)class withParam:(int)parameter
{
    class *operation = [[class alloc] init];

    operation.parameter = parameter;

    [self.queue addOperation:operation];
}
```

or something like that?  i.e. a generic class loader that doesn't care what the class is.

Then I can run...

```
[self createOperationSubclass:MyOperationSubclass withParam:10];
[self createOperationSubclass:MyOtherOperationSubclass withParam:5];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
- (void)createOperationSubclass:(Class)aClass withParam:(int)parameter
{
    id operation = [[aClass alloc] init];

    [operation setParameter:parameter];

    // If your parameter is an NSNumber: [operation setParameter:@(parameter)];

    [self.queue addOperation:operation];
}
```

Then you just call it like:

```
[self createOperationSubclass:[WhateverClass class] withParam:1];
```

PS: Note that `class` is a reserved keyword so it's changed to `aClass`

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly (with one change). Because I'm using id I had to change the parameter to an object (NSNumber*) and had to use [operation setValue:@(parameter) forKey:@"parameter"];  Other than that it worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Nice solution. Much better then my idea :)

Comment: @Fogmeister Glad that helped you. You could also do something like this since you're using object literals: `operation.parameter = @(parameter);`

Comment: It didn't like that though as id didn't have a reference to the property "parameter".

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you do a if/else combination and look which class you got with

```
if ([myObject isKindOfClass:[AnObject class]]) {
    // create object
}
```

Wouldn't that be much easier?

Comment: If he have 10 classes, he will have 10 ifs?

Comment: Yeah, that would just move the problem I currently have into a new function.

Comment: Okey, got it. Upvoted it, also interested in another solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Use APIs like-

```
   NSStringFromClass(Class aClass);
```

or

```
NSClassFromString(NSString *aClassName);
```